# Adjust Search Form on Navbar Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Trying to Get this code working so the Hamburger Glyphicon, and the Nav-Brand are on the left hand side then on the right hand side from (Left - Right) I would have the search form -> Message Glyph -> User Glyph

I have it in the correct order now, but for some reason I cannot get the Search form to the other side unless i use Pull-right and it puts it on the opposite side of the Glyphs

```
    <!-- Navigational Bar -->
<nav id="navbar" class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button href="#menu-toggle" class="slidebar-toggle" id="menu-toggle">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger blue"></span>
        </button>
            <span><a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Title</a></span>
    </div>  
    <!-- Menu & Search Items Right Side of Navbar -->
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse pull-right">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="alerts"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment blue"></i></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="alerts" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user blue"></i><b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="/"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i> link 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> Link 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></i>  Link 3</a></li>      
                        </ul>
                    </li>        
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="search_block_top" class="col-sm-8 clearfix"> 
            <form class="navbar-form" role="search">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="srch-term" id="srch-term">
                        <div class="input-group-btn">
                            <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search blue"></i></button>
                        </div>
                </div>
            </form>     
        </div>
</nav>
```

Just looking for a way to get that Search form moved over to the right, any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the `search_block_top` div above the `navbar-collapse` div, remove the `col-sm-8` class and `clearfix` class and give it a class of `pull-right`